# Is there a way to check if the current LI element has a certain element, such as UL using css?

Tags: css

I want to check if the current li has a ul, if so apply style to the li. is there a way to do this in css?

Answer (score 0):

The following applies styles to the child `ul`s of a `li`:

`li ul li { color:red }`

http://jsfiddle.net/bkC36/

To check if a `click`ed `li` has a `ul` inside of it you need `JavaScript`

Comment: this styles the `ul` not the `li`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to do it is simple.    $('li').has('ul').css('background-color', 'red');

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Tricks discusses what you want here](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) - it's called parent selector, and it's not a great idea to implement. Generally I'll use jQuery to apply styles to a parent if the child exists.

Answer (score 0):

are you wanting to know if an element (li) has a certain child element (ul), and if so, style the parent element (li)?

if so -- no, there is no way to style a parent based on it's children in pure css.  However, jQuery has selectors that allow you to get nodes that match this pattern, which you can then apply styles to.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should apply a style to any li that has a ul at any level bellow it.

```css
ul li {/* */}
```

If you want to style a li that has a ul directly bellow it you can use this rule

```css
ul > li {/* */}
```